# Using DATEDIFF in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, datediff

I am using DATEDIFF in an SQL statement.  I am selecting it, and I need to use it in WHERE clause as well.  This statement does not work...

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, BegTime, EndTime) AS InitialSave
FROM MyTable
WHERE InitialSave <= 10
```

It gives the message: *Invalid column name "InitialSave"*

But this  statement works fine...

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, BegTime, EndTime) AS InitialSave
FROM MyTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(ss, BegTime, EndTime) <= 10
```

The programmer in me says that this is inefficient (seems like I am calling the function twice).

So two questions.  Why doesn't the first statement work?  Is it inefficient to do it using the second statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access columns defined in the select statement in the where statement, because they're not generated until after the where has executed.

You can do this however

```
select InitialSave from 
(SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, BegTime, EndTime) AS InitialSave
FROM MyTable) aTable
WHERE InitialSave <= 10
```

As a sidenote - this essentially moves the DATEDIFF into the where statement in terms of where it's first defined.  Using functions on columns in where statements causes indexes to not be used as efficiently and should be avoided if possible, however if you've got to use datediff then you've got to do it!

Comment: So if I am selecting 20 columns in addition to this, I will need to SELECT them in both statements (inner and outer), correct?  Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want, you can just use select * on the first line, rather than select InitialSave, Col2, Col3 etc etc.

Comment: Oh, duh!  Thanks!  *slaps self on head*

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** When I originally wrote this answer I said that an index on one of the columns could create a query that performs better than other answers (and mentioned Dan Fuller's). However, I was not thinking 100% correctly. The fact is, without a computed column or indexed (materialized) view, a full table scan is going to be *required*, because the two date columns being compared are from the *same* table!

I believe there is still value in the information below, namely 1) the possibility of improved performance in the right situation, as when the comparison is between columns from different tables, and 2) promoting the habit in SQL developers of following best practice and reshaping their thinking in the right direction.

**Making Conditions Sargable**

The best practice I'm referring to is one of moving one column to be alone on one side of the comparison operator, like so:

```
SELECT InitialSave = DateDiff(second, T.BegTime, T.EndTime)
FROM dbo.MyTable T
WHERE T.EndTime <= T.BegTime + '00:00:10'
```

As I said, this will not avoid a scan on a single table, however, in a situation like this it could make a huge difference:

```
SELECT InitialSave = DateDiff(second, T.BegTime, T.EndTime)
FROM
   dbo.BeginTime B
   INNER JOIN dbo.EndTime E
      ON B.BeginTime <= E.EndTime
      AND B.BeginTime + '00:00:10' > E.EndTime
```

`EndTime` is in both conditions now alone on one side of the comparison. Assuming that the `BeginTime` table has many fewer rows, and the `EndTime` table has an index on column `EndTime`, this will perform far, far better than anything using `DateDiff(second, B.BeginTime, E.EndTime)`. It is now *sargable*, which means there is a valid "search argument"--so as the engine *scans* the `BeginTime` table, it can *seek* into the `EndTime` table. Careful selection of which column is by itself on one side of the operator is required--it can be worth experimenting by putting `BeginTime` by itself by doing some algebra to switch to `AND B.BeginTime > E.EndTime - '00:00:10'`

**Precision of DateDiff**

I should also point out that `DateDiff` does not return *elapsed* time, but instead counts the number of *boundaries* crossed. If a call to `DateDiff` using seconds returns `1`, this could mean `3 ms` elapsed time, or it could mean `1997 ms`! This is essentially a precision of +- 1 time units. For the better precision of +- 1/2 time unit, you would want the following query comparing `0` to `EndTime - BegTime`:

```
SELECT DateDiff(second, 0, EndTime - BegTime) AS InitialSave
FROM MyTable
WHERE EndTime <= BegTime + '00:00:10'
```

This now has a maximum rounding error of only one second total, not two (in effect, a floor() operation). Note that you can only subtract the `datetime` data type--to subtract a `date` or a `time` value you would have to convert to `datetime` or use other methods to get the better precision (a whole lot of `DateAdd`, `DateDiff` and possibly other junk, or perhaps using a higher precision time unit and dividing).

This principle is especially important when counting larger units such as hours, days, or months. A `DateDiff` of `1 month` could be 62 days apart (think July 1, 2013 - Aug 31 2013)!

Comment: That's just silly. I wasn't affecting a snooty air when I made that comment, but actually trying to be really helpful to someone who might not know the practical effects of the things I was describing. Please reread what I wrote: was I perhaps just a tiny bit too exact, but not actually insulting?

Comment: Oh... and -1 on my *better-performing* query because of a single word you misunderstood is... fill in the blank here, but it's not complimentary. Hey, man, I was trying to share what I can.

Answer (score 3):

**beyond making it "work", you need to use an index**

use a computed column with an index, or a view with an index, otherwise you will table scan.  when you get enough rows, you will feel the **PAIN** of the slow scan!

computed column & index:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD
    ComputedDate  AS DATEDIFF(ss,BegTime, EndTime)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyTable_ComputedDate  ON MyTable 
    (
    ComputedDate
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

create a view & index:

```
CREATE VIEW YourNewView
AS
SELECT
    KeyValues
        ,DATEDIFF(ss, BegTime, EndTime) AS InitialSave
    FROM MyTable
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourNewView
    ON YourNewView(InitialSave)
GO
```

Comment: Creating indexes on views is not always the magic bullet. I think you will find that an index on the EndTime column will perform well enough and won't have the update overhead. It does come down a little to the update/select pattern.

Comment: This is a really good point, and using a computed column really depends on the data and the frequency of the column being used.

If the table that the column is being used for is likely to be large (as in, millions of rows +) and the column in question is either:
1.  Going to be used extremely frequently in the general running of the application
2.  Going to be accessed infrequently be executive level staff that require quick access.

Then the computed column should be used.  Otherwise it might be better to not use it and not slow down your inserts/updates.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the function instead of the column alias - it is the same with count(*), etc. PITA.

Comment: Is it smart enough to *not* go through the same extensive calculations multiple times?  I am doubtful.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate, you can use [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx).